# Error inflating class ImageView in Navigation Drawer Fragment

Tags: android, android-resources, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

I'm getting Error in **inflating class ImageView** in Fabric Crashlytics:

```
# OS Version: 7.0
# Device: Galaxy S6
# RAM Free: 35.1%
# Disk Free: 44.8%

#0. Crashed: main
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2927(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 2988(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1631(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop + 154(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6682(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 1520(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 1410(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

--

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mydomain.myapp/com.mydomain.myapp.activities.TabActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2927(ActivityThread.java:2927)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 2988(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1631(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop + 154(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6682(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 1520(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 1410(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView


Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView


Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView


Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f08005e


Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f08005e
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName + 240(ResourcesImpl.java:240)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie + 737(ResourcesImpl.java:737)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable + 621(ResourcesImpl.java:621)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable + 1727(Resources.java:1727)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable + 945(TypedArray.java:945)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:157)
at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:145)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView + 182(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView + 106(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView + 1266(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView + 1316(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView + 193(LayoutInflater.java:193)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag + 776(LayoutInflater.java:776)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag + 734(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate + 865(LayoutInflater.java:865)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren + 828(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 525(LayoutInflater.java:525)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 427(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at com.mydomain.myapp.fragments.menu.FragmentDrawer.onCreateView + 115(FragmentDrawer.java:115)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView + 2439(Fragment.java:2439)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView + 1689(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1689)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1431(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1431)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1684(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1684)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment + 1930(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1930)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView + 3745(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3745)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView + 120(FragmentController.java:120)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView + 405(FragmentActivity.java:405)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView + 387(FragmentActivity.java:387)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag + 784(LayoutInflater.java:784)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag + 734(LayoutInflater.java:734)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate + 865(LayoutInflater.java:865)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren + 828(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude + 1011(LayoutInflater.java:1011)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate + 861(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren + 828(LayoutInflater.java:828)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 525(LayoutInflater.java:525)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 427(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate + 378(LayoutInflater.java:378)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView + 469(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView + 140(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.mydomain.myapp.activities.TabActivity.onCreate + 93(TabActivity.java:93)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate + 6942(Activity.java:6942)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate + 1126(Instrumentation.java:1126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2880(ActivityThread.java:2880)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 2988(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1631(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop + 154(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6682(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 1520(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 1410(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

And this is **navigation_drawer_fragment.xml**:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/px_149"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sample_description"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/back_nav_new_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_profile"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/px_64"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/px_64"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sample_description"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_avatar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iv_header"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_header" />

<com.mydomain.myapp.customviews.widgets.TvText
    android:id="@+id/nav_header_fullname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/px_30"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/black_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_15"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iv_profile"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_profile" />

<com.mydomain.myapp.customviews.widgets.Btn
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    style="@style/AppTheme.RoundedCornerStyle"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/px_65"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/px_30"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/px_4"
    android:text="@string/xml_log_and_reg_btn_login"
    android:textColor="@color/black_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_13"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iv_profile"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_profile" />

<com.mydomain.myapp.customviews.widgets.TvTextNumLight
    android:id="@+id/nav_header_phonenumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/px_30"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/sample_mobile"
    android:textColor="@color/black_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_15"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/drawer_list"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iv_profile" />

<com.mydomain.myapp.customviews.widgets.Btn
    android:id="@+id/btn_register"
    style="@style/AppTheme.RoundedCornerStyle"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/px_65"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/px_30"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/px_4"
    android:text="@string/register"
    android:textColor="@color/black_text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_13"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btn_login"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_login" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_launch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sample_description"
    android:scaleX="-1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launch"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_header_phonenumber"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/nav_header_fullname"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_profile"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.68" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/px_8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_header" />
```

And **XML file line #9** refers to:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/px_149"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sample_description"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/back_nav_new_color"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I should note that I put **back_nav_new_color.png** in both **drawable** and **drawable-xhdpi** folders but not in other drawable folders.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: confirm that the resource (@drawable/back_nav_new_color)  exists in your drawable folder. If so try changing the name of the resource to something else

Comment: as I said in my post, I put back_nav_new_color.png in both drawable and drawable-xhdpi folders but not in other drawable folders.

Comment: rename the drawable to something without **new** in it.

Comment: all other **drawable extension** folders without the target image in it will fall back to **drawable** folder so not having similar image inside those folders should not be a problem if the image exist in **drawable** folder

Comment: Try to migrate to Androidx for Example use `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` and `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

Comment: @GiddyNaya are you kidding me about renaming my drawable file!?

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Comment: @GiddyNaya You know... I've never seen this crash in my own devices. just Crashlytics says that 4 users' devices have been crashed 17 times because of this problem, so I cannot test it in my own devices.

Comment: @sausagerus I'll try it.

Comment: why not add images for the other drawable screen sizes or just leave a single persistent image inside main **drawable** folder alone. Just thinking out loud though.

Comment: @GiddyNaya I wanted to display another size of this file in `xhdpi` device screen sizes. I think it's not important in this problem.